# Field extension $\Bbb Q (\zeta_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, factoring, cyclotomic-fields

This is for a quick verification.

Define the $p$th cyclotomic polynomial

$$\Phi_p(X) = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1}X^k$$

where $p$ is an odd prime.

If I understand correctly, the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_p = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$ is $\Phi_p$ and so can we write

$$\Bbb Q (\zeta_p) \cong \Bbb Q[X]/(\Phi_p)$$

where $(\Phi_p)$ is the ideal generated by $\Phi_p$. If I am wrong, why am I wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong. It's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It's worth stressing that the form you give is only correct for primes. The general case is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).